# Android 11 AVD takes up much more storage space than Android 10 AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-11

I completely reinstalled Android Studio and created 2 identical AVDs (Android virtual devices), with the Google-recommended images of Android 10 and one with Android 11, and started my small GMaps-based app on them, nothing more. (After creation, you need to run the AVD at least once so it sets itself up.)

[image]

For some reason the Android 11 AVD is 2.6x larger in terms of size on disk than the Android 10 AVD, **8.9 GB instead of 3.4 GB.** Since I like to have multiple devices to test on this matters to me. **Is this expected and is there something I can do about it?**

Answer (score 0):

I guess its just normal but you can try wiping data once but in my opinion it is totally normal for example in my case API 23 takes 5.2GB where as API 29 takes 12 GB

Comment: Hm, I would prefer if your answer cited some source or explained what's going on.